# How can I create a button that creates a label tag whenever ran?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to create a `<label>` with a unique value, everytime a userclicks a button.

html

```
<button onclick="create()">test</button>
```

js

```
function create() {
  var on = "<label>1</label>"
  $(on).insertAfter("button");
}
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Create an array of anonymous functions, and call `test[2]()`.

Comment: Please tell me: in what situation would that be useful?

Comment: Ain't that exactly what *function parameters* are for?! What's the difference between `test1()` and `test(1)`, except that the latter one makes sense? If you can dynamically create functions, then you can also simply dynamically evaluate the parameter inside the function.

Comment: I mean you could do `window["test" + i] = function()` but then you couldn't call `test2()` before that line as the function wouldn't be hoisted. But I agree with @Bergi don't do this :)

Comment: Please see my updates question.

Comment: No, you don't solve the "infinite button" problem by creating new functions; wrong thinking. You just need one function that reacts to all buttons and you distinguish which button was pressed by passing parameters.

Comment: @deceze Could I please have an example of what you are saying?

Comment: Please do not add meta messages to your titles. As you can see, even after this was reopened, there is a risk that redundant information is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be storing your functions inside an array

```js
let functions = [()=>console.log("func. 1"), ()=>console.log("func. 2")];

for(let i=0; i<functions.length; i++){
  functions[i]();
}
```

Comment: `for (let fn of functions) fn()` :-)